# WP7: navigate twice back

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, navigation

is there a way to navigate two pages back in Windows Phone 7? I know the URI, but I'd like to clear the navigation stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can programmatically walk back the stack. I would recommend reading this guidance doc on this topic:

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Microsoft Silverlight

Comment: it's still kinda sad that the platform does not have this natively.

Comment: btw, the code of the NonlinearNavigationService (proposed by above blog post) is hard to find since microsoft moved it. It can be found here: https://github.com/konstantin-komelin/catchsmile-wp7/tree/master/NonLinearNavigationService

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is like this:

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

This doesn't exactly go back twice, it removes the previous page from the navigation stack, then goes back once, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This could help you out in case you are trying to navigate to your home page.

```
int depth = NavigationService.BackStack.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < depth-1; i++)
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
NavigationService.GoBack();
```