# Windows Phone Back Key Behaviour When Options Appear

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing an app. A page showing full image and when you tap on the image, image caption and sound options appear from two opposite sides i.e caption from left and sound options from right with translate animations.
I want to be clear about that when I press back button, I can navigate to back page or I have to make those options disappear first and then again press back key to go to previous page from microsoft certification point of view?

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: I read the question as: "Can you navigate back a page or do I have to make those options disappear first and then back to go to the previous page." To be honest, it has been a while for me, but as the audio and caption options appear as an action on the current  page, it might be that the back button does what is needed. Unless I have missed something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same since windows phone 7.

You should be allowed to capture the back event and add some code. I don't think that is seen as bad practice, you just aren't allow to stop it.

Saying that, I don't think you can easily do a double back. you might have to check.

Here is a fairly useful post on the subject: 
[WP7: navigate twice back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628237/wp7-navigate-twice-back)

which leads to another post about navigating the stack:
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx

Comment: I guess you meant Windows *Phone* 7.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that is where I was going. I just missed all the letters that spell phone on my keyboard :)

Comment: So if I don't make my options disappear and directly navigate to back page, is there any chances of my application rejection???

Comment: The big back is the one that finally exits the application. Stop that and they will reject it. have you read the posts?